# Frameworks for group chat mobile app server

Tags: django, server, mobile-application

I am setting up server for a group chat mobile application. It is a purely group chatting application i.e. each message will go to multiple recipients. Hence I am choosing HTTP over XMPP.

Also given my back ground in Python, I have started developing the server as -"Apache + Django + MySQL".

Please suggest if there are better alternatives. If the current set up is good enough then also let me know, so that i keep on developing peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

How important is the server vs the app for you? Could you consider hosting the app on a cloud service? Since we are the developers of https://apptimate.io, the most secure point-2-multi point communication service, includung strong encrypion and other goodies, we would like to invite you to take a look att what we can do for you as an alternative.

If you use our backend service you focus on the iOS, Android or HTML5/JS part of the application.